# FORM=ID ATTR=ID Fixed

Tags: imacros

`TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Foto<SP>/<SP>Vídeo
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Carregar<SP>fotos/vídeo
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:u_i_1 ATTR=NAME:file1 CONTENT=C:\Users\katabruk\Downloads\Pasta<SP>Teste\Teste1.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:u_i_1 ATTR=ID:u_jsonp_2_2g CONTENT=kata
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Adicionar<SP>data`

I need Help in This code: `FORM=ID:**u_i_1** and ATTR=ID:**u_jsonp_2_2g**`
Always need to change this ID, there is some fixed code to override this ID??
*ps: This macro is for programming post on facebook

Answer (score 0):

You should try finding the tag using other attributes instead of the id. For example:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ONSUBMIT:"onsubmit event" ATTR=PLACEHOLDER:"placeholder" CONTENT="input content"
```

This works for my auto-sharing macro.

Ref: personal experiance